# Package install using bitbucket private repo

Tags: javascript, json, github, bitbucket

I have created a package for my application and stored it in private repo in bitbucket. Now if someone uses my package in package.json like this

```
"dependencies": {
"mypackage": "git+https://token_here:x-oauth-basic@github.com/user/repository.git"
}
```

This downloads the files from bit-bucket repo to my node_modules folder. The problem is i do not want my token to get exposed in package.json. It should be something like `${Github_token}` or `${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}` like GitHub workflow. Is it possible??

I tried storing the token in env file but i keep getting permission denied error.

Comment: Don't use https, use SSH and have everyone add a SSH key with access to their SSH agent. They'll be able run `npm install` only if they are logged in to bitbucket

Comment: ``authenticated via ssh key. You can use git to connect to bit-bucket. Shell access is disabled`` Still says permission denied. what will be the key value in package.json ?